# forward-char and prettify-symbols-mode interaction

Tags: elisp

I'm using `prettify-symbols-mode` with this basic setting:

```cl
(setq prettify-symbols-alist
      '(("lambda" . ?λ)))
```

When I'm before the lambda, and e.g. the point is 50, and I press
<kbd>C-f</kbd>, the point will increase by 6 to 56.

However, in the same situation `(call-interactively 'forward-char)` will advance the point only by 1.  What am I missing here? I'd like `(call-interactively 'forward-char)` to advance the point by 6.

Comment: The question is incomplete because you don't say *how* you execute `(call-interactively 'forward-char)`.  E.g. if I try it with `M-:` it does advance by 6 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is simple: `forward-char` always only advances by 1 char.  It's the top-level read-eval-loop which then advances an extra 5 chars to move point away from the inside of the composed text.

Comment: Is there an easy way to add an overlay on top of a composed char? If I add an overlay over "l" from "lambda", "λ" becomes decomposed.

Comment: I find it surprising that just adding an overlay would do that.  But of course, if your overlay has properties that affect display (such as `face`, or `display`), then indeed it may break the composition.

Comment: What can we do to go only one line below instead of forward one char?